# select2 - remove inputTooShort text

Tags: jquery-select2

How can I remove "Please enter 1 or more characters" text so when I start to type it will not show this message.

```
$("#js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json', 
      cache: false
    },  
    minimumInputLength: 1   
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override ***inputTooShort*** property in ***language*** option:

```
$("#js-example-basic-multiple").select2({

        language: {
            inputTooShort: function(args) {
                return "";
            }
        }

})
```

Note that there is a bug in select2 library oldiest versions: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3343

Comment: "Please enter 1 or more characters" is not a placeholder, it appears in drop down when you place mouse on input field.

Comment: this would still open the dropdown menu with no options